# Two text fields having similar properties and unable to input values in watir

Tags: watir-webdriver

I have the below two similar properties for 2 text boxes in the DOM:

```
<input type="text" class="promptEditBoxField promptEditBoxFieldWidth" name="saw_18811_9_1" id="saw_18811_9_1_D" tabindex="0" title="" style="width: 120px;">

<input type="text" class="promptEditBoxField promptEditBoxFieldWidth" name="saw_18811_a_1" id="saw_18811_a_1_D" tabindex="0" title="" style="width: 120px;">
```

The only one which comes returns true or exists is the class which is the same for both the class:

```
@browser.input(:class, "promptEditBoxField promptEditBoxFieldWidth").exists?
#=> true
```

However, with this I am able to input value only in one text field and not able to do the same for the second text field. Though the ID and name is different it doesn't help as it returns false (doesn't exist).

Comment: Not sure why everything that I type doesnt get updated the first time. Trying to add what got trimmed off now. <input type="text" class="promptEditBoxField promptEditBoxFieldWidth" name="saw_18811_9_1" id="saw_18811_9_1_D" tabindex="0" title="" style="width: 120px;">

<input type="text" class="promptEditBoxField promptEditBoxFieldWidth" name="saw_18811_a_1" id="saw_18811_a_1_D" tabindex="0" title="" style="width: 120px;"> Though the ID and name is unique, it doesnt help as it returns false (doesnt exist). Any help?

Comment: It would probably help to show what you tried for locating the second text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try someth about:

`@browser.text_fields(:class => "promptEditBoxField promptEditBoxFieldWidth")[0].set 'your text'` - for first input

`@browser.text_fields(:class => "promptEditBoxField promptEditBoxFieldWidth")[1].set 'your text'` - second and etc.

also, it can be more ease, just take all `text_fields` from your web-page:

```
@browser.text_fields
```

This return all text_fields from page, after just: `@browser.text_fields[0]`, `@browser.text_fields[1]`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alex and  the code above works perfectly and gave me the expected results. Thanks Justin for making my question more readable and let me know if I am doing anything wrong in drafting my question as most of the times once I submit few what I typed automatically trimms off.